# awk subtract each row of a column from 1 where row greater than .5

Tags: awk

I have:

```
col
.4
.3
.7
```

I want:

```
col
.4
.3
.3
```

My column is one column amongst others, I only want to apply this math to this column only while leaving all others unchanged. I want to print all columns (after applying the math).

I tried this:

```
awk '{print $0, ($1 > .5 ? 1 - $1 : $1)}'
```

but does not seem to work.

Comment: Can you explain what "_does not seem to work_" means? Please show the output and explain why it is wrong.

Comment: Leaves column of interest unchanged

Comment: You're not actually changing the column of interest, you're adding a new column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print $0, ($1 > .5 ? 1 - $1 : $1)` adds an extra column, it does not change the existing ones. Try:

```
$ awk 'NR>1 && $1>.5 {$1 = 1-$1} {print}' file
col
.4
.3
0.3
```

If you don't like the leading zeros (`0.3`) try:

```
$ awk 'NR>1 && $1>.5 {$1=1-$1;sub(/0*/,"",$1)} {print}' file
col
.4
.3
.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of thinking:

```
awk '$1~/\.[6-9]/ {$1=1-$1;sub("^0","",$1)} 1' file
col
.4
.3
.3
```

if it's only one digit after point, then it should work, otherwise use normal way.